# Gnome Desktop Shortcuts to Files on Removable Media keep Disappearing. How to prevent?

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, desktop

Problem exists on: Ubuntu 20.04/21.04

Whenever I create desktop shortcuts (in /home/username/.local/share/applications) to scripts that are located on removable media, they keep disappearing after reboot. I usually create copies of the shortcuts and also place these on the desktop. Recently, the desktop ones remain there and are accessible, but those that appear under "Show Applications" button, as well as the Applications Menu (enabled through extensions), as well as on the Side Panel (where Favorites usually show up), still disappear after reboot.

It doesn't help if I create symbolic links to the actual scripts in my home directory and point the desktop shortcuts to those symbolic links. The problem is only resolved when I place the scripts themselves anywhere on my permanent harddrive, but this is not a viable option.

Comment: As a workaround, I create actual scripts on my harddrive, that however simply invoke the actual target scripts. Now the desktop shortcuts are persistent after reboots.